# Create a Countdown Timer in Android Action Bar

Tags: java, android, timer, android-actionbar

I'm having trouble creating a countdown timer that is viewed from the action bar. Right now this is my menu_main.xml and part of my MainActivity.java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    undoValuesA.add(scoreTeamA);
    undoValuesB.add(scoreTeamB);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        scoreTeamA = savedInstanceState.getInt(SCORE_TEAM_A_KEY);
        scoreTeamB = savedInstanceState.getInt(SCORE_TEAM_B_KEY);
        undoValuesA = savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList(UNDO_A_KEY);
        undoValuesB = savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList(UNDO_B_KEY);
    }
    displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);

    swish = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.swish);

    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    textViewTime.setText("3:00");



}



<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:title = "0:00"
    android:id = "@+id/timer"
    app:showAsAction = "always"

    />
<item android:id="@+id/action_plus"
    android:title="Plus"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_plus"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_minus"
    android:title="minus"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_minus"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

My app is crashing because the timer in the action bar isn't a textview, merely an item. So, when i try to use textViewTime.setText("3:00"); it crashes upon start. 
How would I implement this?

Comment: MenuItem has a setTitle method instead of setText

Comment: Here is an Example: http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/07/android-count-down-timer-in-actionbar.html

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Implement your "count-down timer" as a custom `View` class, such as this `ReverseChronometer` implementation:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.preso.slides;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReverseChronometer extends TextView implements Runnable {
  long startTime=0L;
  long overallDuration=0L;
  long warningDuration=0L;
  boolean isRunning=false;

  public ReverseChronometer(Context context) {
    super(context);

    reset();
  }

  public ReverseChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    reset();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    isRunning=true;

    long elapsedSeconds=
        (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime) / 1000;

    if (elapsedSeconds < overallDuration) {
      long remainingSeconds=overallDuration - elapsedSeconds;
      long minutes=remainingSeconds / 60;
      long seconds=remainingSeconds - (60 * minutes);

      setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

      if (warningDuration > 0 && remainingSeconds < warningDuration) {
        setTextColor(0xFFFF6600); // orange
      }
      else {
        setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      }

      postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
    else {
      setText("0:00");
      setTextColor(Color.RED);
      isRunning=false;
    }
  }

  public void reset() {
    startTime=SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    setText("--:--");
    setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  }

  public void stop() {
    removeCallbacks(this);
    isRunning=false;
  }

  public boolean isRunning() {
    return(isRunning);
  }

  public void setOverallDuration(long overallDuration) {
    this.overallDuration=overallDuration;
  }

  public void setWarningDuration(long warningDuration) {
    this.warningDuration=warningDuration;
  }
}
```

Step #2: Use `android:actionViewClass` (or, in your case, `app:actionViewClass`) to point to the class from step #1 in your menu resource, such as this for the native action bar:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/countdown"
    android:actionViewClass="com.commonsware.android.preso.slides.ReverseChronometer"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="This Should Not Be Needed">
</item>
```

Step #3: Retrieve that action item and configure it from your Java code, such as this for the native action bar:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_actions, menu);

    ReverseChronometer rc=(ReverseChronometer)menu
                                                .findItem(R.id.countdown)
                                                .getActionView();

    rc.setOverallDuration(40*60);
    rc.setWarningDuration(5*60);
    rc.setOnClickListener(this);
    rc.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    rc.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
    rc.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }
```

You would need to make appropriate adjustments to Step #2 and Step #3, as you are using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport.

Comment: Why not just use setTitle instead of adding all this complexity?

Comment: @DavidM: In my app, I did not want to use the title for this role. This implementation also offers features (e.g., pause, color coding) that would be difficult or impossible to accomplish with the action bar title. Plus, this more closely mimics what the OP was attempting with the OP's own code. You are welcome to use the title if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I implemented all of the code, but there's one issue.
    rc.setOnClickListener(this);
    rc.setOnLongClickListerner(this);
give me errors, saying "in View cannot be applied" to MainActivity
Sorry I'm still really new to Java and Android, what do I do from here?

Comment: @JesseZhang: Either comment out those lines, or have `MainActivity` implement the `View.OnClickListener` and `View.OnLongClickListener` interfaces.